# Homework - Preemptive Priority Scheduling

Tags: process, cpu, scheduling

```
Process     Burst Time     Arrival Time     Priority
P1          5              0                1
P2          1              0                3
P3          2              2                1
P4          4              4                2
P5          2              4                2
P6          3              5                3
P7          4              5                3
```

Hi guys. We're given an assignment about Preemptive Priority Scheduling and I really don't know how to do this given two or more processes having the same priority number.

I have to make a gantt chart, compute turn-around time, and average waiting time.

If possible, can you guys post a step-by-step solution on how to do it so that I can study how it's done.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: If this is a conceptual question, it would be better suited for [programmers.se] or possibly [theoretical.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: two processes with the same priority will generally be sorted according to their arrival time: so first come first serve.

Turn around time: generally refers to the amount of time required for the process to produce output. Your course may use a different or simpler definition to make your calculations easier. From what I can see you are probably being asked to compute the amount of time it takes for each process to complete. This is equal to: `finish_time - time_first_scheduled_on_CPU` (not `finish_time - arrival_time`).

Average waiting time: Based on the Gantt chart you develop which shows exactly when and for how long a process is on the CPU, you can compute the total amount of time each process was waiting to get on the CPU.

This consists of:

1. Amount of time between arrival and when it is first scheduled on the CPU
2. If the process has a longer execution time than a single quantum then you need to sum all of the time spent **off** the CPU
3. Add the two quantities together and you have the total waiting time for the process
4. Repeat steps 1-3 for each process and take the average.

Comment: Hmmm. From my example, P1 and P3's priority is 1...
P1's arrival time is 0 but has a burst time of 5.
P3's arrival time is 2 but has a burst time of 2.

Should P1 finish all 5 units first before going to P3's 2 units?
or P1 will finish 1 unit first then let P3 have 2 units then finish the 4?

Comment: P1 will run to completion because P3 has the same priority. Think of it like this: a General can pre-empt a Lieutenant, but a Lieutenant cannot pre-empt a General. Most importantly, all Lieutenants are equal, so Lieutenant A cannot pre-empt Lieutenant B.

Comment: <pre>
Ok, noted. Thanks.

Another question. What about the case of P4 and P5. They both have the same priority numbers and the same arrival time. the only difference is their burst time.

How do I deal with that? :)
</pre>

Comment: P4 and P5 sounds like a badly worded question to me. On a single processor system that is not really going to happen because that implies two things happening at once. Setting aside that technicality though, what happens is really dependent on the policy of the scheduler. I would suggest that the most likely thing is that P4 will be executed before P5 simply because that is the order in which they appear in the question. Again, insufficient information to make a conclusion

Comment: that's what I thought too...
although ambiguous, I guess I'll have to go with the order they appeared.